# Как закинуть проект на slim framework в github?

Tags: git, github

Надо было сделать rest api и залить на github, сделал на slim framework, там почти 500 файлов.Как такое вообще показывают, не перекидывать же частями.Или кидаются папки, которые сам создавал + файл composer?

Comment: Я с пхп не работаю, но подозреваю, что в репозиторий проекта создается файл `.gitignore` в котором прописываются все директории в кот. лежат файлы фреймворка. Далее делается коммит и пуш на гитхаб.

Comment: Да наверное так и сделаю, можно даже просто перетащить всё кроме файлов фреймворка, а не через терминал.Спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Предполагается, что git на компьютере уже установлен*

Сначала нужно определиться, какие файлы будут исключены из репозитория (обычно это вендорные пакеты, ЕНВ-файлы, файлы конфигов, включающие тайную информацию - явки, пароли и т.д.)

Для этого нужно создать файл `.gitignore`:

```
vendor/
```

Если настройки/пароли лежат в файле `.env`, то добавляем строчку в `.gitignore`

```
vendor/
.env
```

И добавляем файл `.env.exapmle`, в котором описываем, какая переменная для чего нужна

В общем, таким образом исключаем из репозитория то, что туда не должно попасть.

`composer.json` всегда оставляем в репозитории, `composer.lock` оставляем в проектах, но исключаем в библиотеках.

Далее, в профиле гитхаба создаем репозиторий и берём его ссылку. Yапример, если логин в гитхабе `username`, а репозиторий назвали `project`, то ссылка будет `https://github.com/username/project.git`, но с такой ссылкой придется каждый раз вводить логин и пароль от гитхаба, поэтому можно настроить ssh-ключи и использовать ссылку `git@github.com:username/project.git`.

Теперь в консоли переходим в папку проекта и выполняем команды:

1. Инициализация репозитория в папке

   ```bsh
   git init
   ```
2. Добавляем ссылку на удаленный репозиторий

   ```bsh
   git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git
   ```
3. Добавляем все файлы в индекс репозитория

   ```bsh
   git add .
   ```
4. Коммитим изменения

   ```bsh
   git commit -m 'Начинаем наш проект!'
   ```
5. Отправляем коммиты во внешний репозиторий

   ```bsh
   git push -u origin master
   ```

Последующие отправки в ветку `master` можно будет делать просто `git push`.

Открываем проект на гитхабе и видим, что файлы загрузились.